# Working with a JSON array with inconsistent Type returned from a callout

Tags: apex, json, parsing

I am making a callout and getting a JSON array in return. My initial thought was to use an Apex Wrapper class and deserialize. Because I need to do some transformations with the values and display them on a LWC.
The challenge I am facing is - there is one integer type value that carries 'null' as an empty value. The code fails because it is expecting an integer. How do I handle it so that null or 0 both mean null?

`````
List<AppointmentWrapper> appointments = (List<AppointmentWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<AppointmentWrapper>.class);````

AppointmentWrapper:
public class AppointmentWrapper {
 
        public Integer uid;
        public Integer mvPatientID; 
        public Integer appointmentID;   
        public Integer csn; 
        public String startTime;    
        public Integer duration;    
        public String visitType;    
        public String patientFirstName;
        public String patientLastName;  
        public String dob;  
        public Integer providerID;  
        @AuraEnabled public String providerFirstName;
        @AuraEnabled public String providerLastName;    
        public String credential;
        public String pennID;
        public Integer npi; 
        public Integer locationID;  
        public String locationName; 
        public String locationDisplayName;  
        public String status;   
        public String email;
        public String cellPhone;
        public String homePhone;    
        public String idxName;
        public Integer idxid;       //the problem key
        public String address1;
        public String address2;
        

}

JSON example: 
[
{
    "uid": 8641654603,
    "mvPatientID": 200000075967,
    "appointmentID": 66542142,
    "csn": 300038330,
    "startTime": "2020-12-28T11:30:00-05:00",
    "duration": 7200,
    "visitType": "Test",
    "patientFirstName": "TEST",
    "patientLastName": "TESTRADIANT",
    "dob": "ssss",
    "providerID": 1000000000282024,
    "providerFirstName": "Test",
    "providerLastName": "Hup",
    "credential": null,
    "pennID": null,
    "npi": 0,
    "locationID": 100000001879,
    "locationName": "TEST",
    "locationDisplayName": "TEST",
    "status": "Completed",
    "email": "test",
    "cellPhone": null,
    "homePhone": "xxxx",
    "idxName": "aaaa",
    "idxid": 6021,
    "address1": "123 MAIN ST",
    "address2": null,
    "city": "TEST",
    "state": "TA",
    "zip": "TEST",
    "externalProviderId": "R12586",
    "sex": "F",
    "language": "SPANISH",
    "preferredName": null,
    "locationPhone": "xxxx",
    "isTeleHealth": false,
    "scheduledDate": "",
    "visitTypeId": null,
    "epicVisitTypeId": null,
    "race": null,
    "ethnicity": null,
    "reportCategoryId": null,
    "reportCategoryName": null,
    "contacts": null
},
{
    "uid": 8641654603,
    "mvPatientID": 200000075967,
    "appointmentID": 66542764,
    "csn": 300039774,
    "startTime": "2021-01-26T13:50:00-05:00",
    "duration": 1800,
    "visitType": "tttt",
    "patientFirstName": "test",
    "patientLastName": "test",
    "dob": "1999-09-09",
    "providerID": 1000000000352046,
    "providerFirstName": null,
    "providerLastName": "TEST",
    "credential": null,
    "pennID": null,
    "npi": 0,
    "locationID": 100000013753,
    "locationName": "TEST",
    "locationDisplayName": "TEST",
    "status": "Completed",
    "email": "test@test",
    "cellPhone": null,
    "homePhone": "(267)xxxxxxx",
    "idxName": "TEST",
    "idxid": null,
    "address1": "123 MAIN ST",
    "address2": null,
    "city": "TEST",
    "state": "TA",
    "zip": "www",
    "externalProviderId": "R82229",
    "sex": "F",
    "language": "SPANISH",
    "preferredName": null,
    "locationPhone": "xxxx",
    "isTeleHealth": false,
    "scheduledDate": "",
    "visitTypeId": null,
    "epicVisitTypeId": null,
    "race": null,
    "ethnicity": null,
    "reportCategoryId": null,
    "reportCategoryName": null,
    "contacts": null
}
`````

Comment: Sorry, we don't have enough information to help from this context. `null`, without quotes, is a legal JSON value, and Apex and JavaScript both have no problem handling this kind of data. Whatever is going on isn't here. P.S. You should [edit] your question instead of adding an answer. Your answer will invariably be deleted and the information not visible to (most) users.

Comment: I updated my question with JSON.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox Since I am using idxid as a Integer, I get  FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException. I realized i wasn't really using the idxid in my LWC, so i removed it from my Wrapper class. And I longer get the error.